# Construct a deterministic Turing machine that decides the language $L=\{w\in\{a, b\}\mid w\text{ contains an occurrence of }ab\}$

Tags: logic, formal-languages, turing-machines

So we are asked to construct a deterministic Turing machine. I have constructed a Turing machine, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Here is my Turing machine:

[image: Turing machine]

For the question above, I'm just making sure I'm on the right track!

The next question is:
Describe in clear English a Turing machine that semi-decides the language

$$L = \{\langle M\rangle\mid M\text{ accepts the binary encodings of at least 3 prime numbers}\}$$

I'm not sure what it means to "semi-decide" a language... So this question, I'm stuck, any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Here is a an example of a Turing machine created out of our textbook. This is for an input string L = {a^i b^j : 0 ≤ j ≤ i}. The output string will then be L = {a^n b^n : 0 ≤ n}.

[image]

EDIT:

Here is my new Turing machine:
[image: Turing Machine]

Thanks!

Comment: Your basic idea will work, but whether the details are right depends on the precise formalization of Turing machines you're working with. Does your concept of Turing machine have a concept of a transition _out of_ a stopping state? That looks a bit strange.

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm not exactly sure. I've been reading it out of our textbook. The name of our textbook is: Automata, Computability and Complexity by Elaine Rich. I'll edit the question and put a Turing machine that they created out of the textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, your basic idea works, but I think you need to be more careful about how your machine will *stop*. Note that in the example machine from the book, there are no transitions out of the stopping state 6; entering a stopping state means that *the machine stops working*.

On the other hand, the example machine does contain transitions for symbols \$, #, and $\Box$ that are not in the alphabet of the input strings. I suspect those symbols are supposed to help the machine find out when it has reached the end of the string; but for details you need to consult the book because different authors use different conventions in this regard. (I'd guess that $\Box$ stands for a blank square of the tape and \$ might signal the end of the input, but I can't offhand guess what the purpose of # would be).

In any case your machine will need to do *something* in case it reaches the end of the input without having seen `ab`. Again you will need to consult the book to find out the exact conventions it uses for how a Turing machine should signal that it "rejects" the input.

---

A Turing machine is said to **semi-decide** a language $L$ iff

1. For all strings $w\in L$, the machine will halt on input $w$.
2. For all strings $w\notin L$, the machine will keep running forever on input $w$.

(There are minor but nonessential differences between authors here. Some allow the machine to halt with either an "accept" or a "reject" output; in that case a semi-deciding Turing machine is allowed to *either* reject *or* run forever when its input is not in $L$).

Thus you're asked to sketch a Turing machine $T$ whose input is a description of a *different* machine $M$, and $T$ should halt if and only if there exists three different primes that $M$ all halt on.

When you're being asked to "describe $T$ in clear English", the main point is that you're *not* supposed to show it state for state (which would be extremely long and unwieldy), but just give a clear *overall* description about how it processes its input.

Comment: In the book the $ and # are what the Turing machine writes in place of a's and b's, respectively, so that it can make sure there are the same number of a's as b's. But I thought a blank would represent the end of the string, so could I add another state, say q3, and make q0 and q1 point to it if they contain a blank square?

Comment: I added the new turing machine to the question!